# R, str_replace, gsub, how to replace a vector of characters for another vector of characters?

Tags: r, string, character

I'm trying to "delete" specific characters from strings in several rows.

I was able to extract the specific characters I want to "delete" from the column, but I'm not able to replace them recursively for "".

I've tried some options with `mapvalues`, `gsub` and `str_replace` but I haven't had any luck

```
#Example data   
test_col<-data.frame(sequence=c("ATGCRYSW\n",
                                   "ATGCRYSW\\n",
                                   "ATGCRYSW\r\n",
                                   "ATGCRYSW\r\nATGCRYSW",
                                   "ATGCRYSW"),
                                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


#vector of allowed characters in strings
permitted_seq_chars<-c("A","C","G","T","R","Y","S","W","K",
                       "M","B","D","H","V","N","+","-","X")



#get all the unique characters in column of interest
all_unique_source_seq_chars<-unique(unlist(strsplit(test_col[["sequence"]],
                                     split ="")))


#subset invalid characters
all_unique_source_seq_invalid_chars<-setdiff(all_unique_source_seq_chars,
                                             permitted_seq_chars )

#'delete' invalid characters one by one. So far the only way I've been able to 
# do so, but i would like to not depend on fixed variables if new ones arise  
# in the future

str_replace_all(test_col$sequence, c( "\n"= "",
                                       "\\"="",
                                       "n"=""))
```

is there any any way to do this recursively just looking at `all_unique_source_seq_invalid_chars`?

Comment: DO you need `pat <- paste0("[^", paste(permitted_seq_chars, collapse=""), "]")
; gsub(pat, "", test_col$sequence)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to `paste` the individual characters as a pattern string wrapped by square brackets to evaluate it literally (in case there are meta characters) and then replace with blank (`""`) in `gsub`

```
pat <- paste0("[^", gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", paste(permitted_seq_chars, collapse="")), "]")
gsub(pat, "", test_col$sequence)
#[1] "ATGCRYSW"         "ATGCRYSW"         "ATGCRYSW"    
#[4] "ATGCRYSWATGCRYSW" "ATGCRYSW"
```

Comment: That's some gsub syntax I didn't know!!. Thanks for that. 

There are some cases where it is better to have a catalog of invalid characters. I was wondering what would be the syntax for "nothing from this pattern" instead of "exclude everything, except for this pattern".